# Height auto makes element disappear

Tags: html, css

I have divs with below CSS, when the height is set to auto div disappears (div with class one).

When height is set to some value in px then its visible (div with class two).

```css
.one,
.two {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(67, 132, 245);
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-size: 40px;
  background-position: center;
}

.one {
  height: auto;
  right: 20px;
}

.two {
  height: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
</div>

<div class="two">
</div>
```

Comment: parent is just empty div element with no css.

Comment: Your div is empty... Height auto, set the height on the content size of the div

Comment: Because both divs have no content. Background image is NOT content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a `div` element has a height of `0px` and a width of `100%`.

> *Edit: as @TemaniAfif pointed out in the comment below, this is not true for `div` elements with a fixed position as you are using. In that case, the default `width` is `0px` as well. However, you specify a width for both of your `div` elements, so changing the `height` property alone changes whether your element is visible or not.*

The default height of a `div` only increases if it has content (such as text, or other elements with a fixed height). Note that here, a `background-image` does not count as content, because it is just a CSS style.

In your example, `div.one` therefore has a height of `0px`, because `height: auto` applies the default value. This is why it appears to be invisible.

`div.two` has a height of `100px`, because that is what you specified for it. Therefore it is visible.

---

**Additional Note:**

What you may be getting confused about is the fact that an `img` element usually resizes automatically to the dimensions of the image it holds. However, the same thing does not apply for a `div` which has a `background-image` set.

Comment: *and a width of 100%.* --> this is not exaclty true because it depends on other properties. In this example, there is the use of position:fixed so the width will also be 0 if not specified

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you very much for that info, I've now updated my answer.